# How to .find tag with an empty attribute value?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Sample HTML

```
<div class="SomeClass" style="">some text<\div>
```

To find this specific tag i`ve tried

```
text = article.find('div', attrs={'style':""})
```

but it finds all tags those HAVE this attribute, no matter empty or not.
How to specify that tag "div" must have an empty "style" attribute?

---

(UPDATED)Found a solution, but it looks a little bit ugly

```
    text_area = article.find_all('div', attrs={'style':''})
    text = []
    for i in text_area:
        if 'style=""' in str(i):
            text.append(i.text)
```

Is there another way to make it look better?

Comment: Not super elegant, but you could `findall` `div` tags, loop through them, check if `has_attr` `style` and if so, check if value is empty string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's to do with the default parser being HTML based where each element has an implicit `style=''` attribute. If you instead specify an XML parser (like `lxml-xml`) it works, but then you may not be able to parse a HTML document

```
>>> html = '<div class="SomeClass" style="">blank<\div><div class="SomeClass" style="test">test<\div><div class="SomeClass">none<\div>'
>>> article = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml-xml')
>>> article.find_all('div', style='')
[<div class="SomeClass" style="">blank</div>]
```

Comment: I think that is the solution, though for me it finds all the tags in block. To say more, in my case the result is strange, lxml-xml does the same as .find_all in html parser, but returns string (as it should be). I think it`s because of specific html. Nevertheless thanks)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> html = '<div class="SomeClass" style="some_styel">some text<\div><div class="SomeClass" style="">some text<\div>'
>>> bs = BS(html, 'html.parser')
>>> divs = bs.find_all('div', {'style': ''})
>>> for div in divs:
...     div['style']
''
```

Comment: Looks a little bit prettier but still is the same solution

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this

```
 matched_rctype = None
 rctypes = form.find_all("option", {'selected':''})
 for rctype in rctypes:
     try:
         rctype['selected']
         matched_rctype = rctype.contents[0]
     except KeyError:
         continue
```